# Pandas: plot Series on a new figure by default

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is there a way to force the `.plot` method of a pandas Series to generate a new figure, instead of trying to plot on the currently open figure?

I currently create a new figure using `plt.figure()` or using `plt.subplots` and passing the axis, but for quick plots from the interactive console it would be great to simply use the `.plot` method without extra lines of code.

I wonder if there are configs in pandas that can be changed to achieve this.

Comment: besides calling plt.show() between each plot, I don't know a better way

Comment: `Series.plot()` should have a `figsize` argument. What happens if you use that? I suppose something like `series.plot(..., ax=plt.subplots()[1])` would also work to get the command in one line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately using figsize does not help. Your second suggestion works, but requires same amount of typing as what I currently do.  (the question is mainly do deal with my laziness!)

Comment: Ok, so you can of course manipulate the source code of pandas. Not sure if that is what you want. Else, you could write a small module and import it each time; this could have a function like `def plot(series, *args, **kwargs): _, ax = plt.subplots(); kwargs.update(ax=ax); series.plot(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: You can use `s.plot(figure=plt.figure())` but if you want to do it often then writing your own function it is probably more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a config. Defining a wrapper around .plot() should do the trick, as suggested by Stop harming Monica.

```
def plot(s, **kwargs):
    s.plot(**kwargs)
    plt.show();
```